# checking if the textbox contain any number

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 2 text boxs and I'm trying to create a JS function that will check if those textboxes are

Including only numbers but nothing seems to work!! any idea why??!?!

If they doesn't contain any numbers so the info would submit.

This is my JS Function:

```
 function checkName(sender, args) {
        var letters = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/";
        var firstName = $find("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
        var l_firstNametxt = firstName.get_value();
        var lastName = $find("<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>");
        var l_lastNametxt = lastName.get_value();
        if (l_firstNametxt = letters) {
            if (l_lastNametxt = letters) {
                alert("nice try!");
            }
        }
        else {
            __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your function.

First, you seem to be trying to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), but in JS a regex literal is declared *without* putting quotation marks around it. So use this:

```
var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;      // NOT var letters = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/";
```

Secondly, in both of your if statements you are *assigning* a value by using `=`, rather than comparing using the `==` or `===` operators, but in any case a regex test is not done with an equals operator, you have to use a regex method such as [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
    if (letters.test(l_firstNametxt)) {
        if (letters.test(l_lastNametxt)) {
```

With those changes your code should at least "work" in a general sense, but it still won't do what you want it to: you said you want to test if the textboxes contain "any number", but the regular expression you are trying to use allows both numbers and letters. To test for "any number" you can use this regex:

```
/[0-9]/
```

...which can be simplified to `/\d/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked "I'm trying to create a JS function that will check if those textboxes are
Including only numbers", a simpler method would be to use the `isNaN()` function.

```
function isNumber(val) {
    if(!isNaN(val))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```